# how to find out the architecture of a chip?Pic or AVR?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, pic

How to find out that a microcontroller is a PIC or AVR?Is the name of microcontroller related to it?What if the name starts with other letters rather than PIC or At ?

Comment: Can you give the id of the chip you want id'd?

Comment: On my pics, it's written `PIC 18F2550-I/SP`. On avr, it's written `ATMEL ATMEGA8 -16PU` like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR#mediaviewer/File:ATmega8_01_Pengo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any other chip, if you don't recognize the family, look it up. The two family names you mention in particular are limited to Microchip and Atmel respectively, and the company logo tends to be a huge clue; but it's not uncommon for companies to produce many architectures. For instance, PIC32 branded chips are MIPS, and Atmel make both ARM and 8051 chips also, aside from having two architectures under the AVR brand (8 and 32 bit). All of these are only processor architectures, which in turn tend to divide into classes (often depending on factors like program memory size), and the peripheral device setup tends to be more important (an Xmega is far different from an ATTiny).

Comment: Hey,Mr.Yann Vernier,it is really encouraging for answering  the question.But how do I program a chip that neither belongs to PIC or AVR.Can you please give me some links that may be helpful for me.

Comment: Not with such a vague question, because that is always family specific. While I've worked on programmers for several different families (including MSP430 and 6808), you need to know the family first, then look for tools related to that family.